# HTTP Caching layer for Rest API

Tags: rest, http, nginx, caching, api-design

I need to design a caching layer for my current concert ticket application. The application involves having a user scan into the application with a wristband that holds specific user details via a barcode. So every time a user signs into the application they need to scan their wristband. There is a Rest API that receives the barcode information and then fetches the corresponding customer information from a client database using java endpoints. The customer data being fetched from the database is in Json format like so:

```
{
  "Concert_ticket_id": " 123",
  "Concert_date": "2018-04-23",
  "Schedule": {
    "Opening_time": "08:00:00",
    "Closing_time": "23:00:00"
  },
  "exception": null
}
```

My goal is to design a caching layer in front of the API so that the application doesn’t need to search through the entire client database every time a customer logs into the application. So ideally, I would like for the user to scan their wristband, then have the API query the client database, log the user into the application, have this wristband information stored in the cache, then have the application pull the login info from this cache instead of the database the next time the user scans their wristband to sign in. Since concert information is updated from time to time, I need to have some way to update the cache if the data is updated in the database.

I’ve looked into Nginx, Apache Server, and some http cache control headers, but I’m not sure how necessary they are. What would be the best approach to designing this type of caching layer?

Comment: Have you thought about redis or memcache?

Comment: Yes I've considered memcaching. Would there be some specific benefit to using it in my case?

Comment: If it is managed via redis or memcache it would make your workflow and management much easier. A request comes in look in memcache. If the data is there then great otherwise get it from the database and store in memcache for next time. Details of concert change then remove all keys from memcache that match that event.